# Angular4.1 with .NET Core1.1 build fails in VSTS Hosted VS2017 agent

Tags: angular, typescript, azure-pipelines, asp.net-core-1.1

I have an Angular 4.1.1 app sitting on .NET Core 1.1 which I recently migrated from VS2015 w/update 3 to VS2017. My csproj builds and runs fine on my local machine but fails when setting up a build on VSTS via their hosted VS2017 agent.

The failure occurs during the "Build" step and here is the portion of the log file indicating the reason:

```html
Installed:
2017-05-27T14:23:05.5884539Z       301 package(s) to d:\a\1\s\src\MyApp.Web\MyApp.Web.csproj
2017-05-27T14:23:05.6244543Z ##[section]Finishing: Restore
2017-05-27T14:23:05.6254542Z ##[section]Starting: Build
2017-05-27T14:23:05.6264541Z ==============================================================================
2017-05-27T14:23:05.6264541Z Task         : .NET Core
2017-05-27T14:23:05.6264541Z Description  : Build, test and publish using dotnet core command-line.
2017-05-27T14:23:05.6264541Z Version      : 1.0.1
2017-05-27T14:23:05.6264541Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2017-05-27T14:23:05.6264541Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=832194)
2017-05-27T14:23:05.6264541Z ==============================================================================
2017-05-27T14:23:05.9804666Z [command]"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" build d:\a\1\s\src\MyApp.Web\Gitrub.Web.csproj --configuration release
2017-05-27T14:23:09.2404951Z Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.1.1012.6693
2017-05-27T14:23:09.2404951Z Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
2017-05-27T14:23:09.2404951Z 
2017-05-27T14:23:14.7693001Z C:\Users\buildguest\.nuget\packages\microsoft.typescript.msbuild\2.2.2\tools\microsoft.TypeScript.targets(168,5): error MSB4062: The "TypeScript.Tasks.FindConfigFiles" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Users\buildguest\.nuget\packages\microsoft.typescript.msbuild\2.2.2\tools\TypeScript.tasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [d:\a\1\s\src\MyApp.Web\MyApp.Web.csproj]
2017-05-27T14:23:15.0284154Z 
2017-05-27T14:23:15.0284154Z Build FAILED.
2017-05-27T14:23:15.0284154Z 
2017-05-27T14:23:15.0284154Z C:\Users\buildguest\.nuget\packages\microsoft.typescript.msbuild\2.2.2\tools\microsoft.TypeScript.targets(168,5): error MSB4062: The "TypeScript.Tasks.FindConfigFiles" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Users\buildguest\.nuget\packages\microsoft.typescript.msbuild\2.2.2\tools\TypeScript.tasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [d:\a\1\s\src\MyApp.Web\MyApp.Web.csproj]
2017-05-27T14:23:15.0284154Z     0 Warning(s)
2017-05-27T14:23:15.0284154Z     1 Error(s)
2017-05-27T14:23:15.0294178Z 
2017-05-27T14:23:15.0294178Z Time Elapsed 00:00:05.73
2017-05-27T14:23:15.0564018Z ##[error]Error: C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe failed with return code: 1
2017-05-27T14:23:15.0564018Z ##[error]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : d:\a\1\s\src\MyApp.Web\MyApp.Web.csproj
```

I noticed on the VSTS Site that Typescript isn't included as part of what is supported by the VS2017 Hosted agent (and up to v2.0.6 for 'Hosted' agent) and I thought this might be the reason for the above error, however I've been able run successful builds on the 'Hosted' agent before I migrated my app to VS2017, while using the SAME version (2.2) of typescript I am trying to deploy now..

I'd appreciate anyone who can help me solve this. Here is my csproj for reference:

```html
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
    <AssemblyName>MyApp.Web</AssemblyName>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <PackageId>MyApp.Web</PackageId>
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>1.1.1</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
    <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);dotnet5.6;portable-net45+win8</PackageTargetFallback>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="wwwroot\**\*">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TypeScript.Compiler" Version="2.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild" Version="2.2.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently setup a similar build and ran into this same problem.  I was able to resolve it by adding a .NET Core step for "dotnet restore."

Comment: Thanks for responding. I am not sure what you are referring to exactly.. There is a 'Restore' step that takes place prior to the 'Build' step and this step goes thru fine. Other than this I am not following..

Answer (score 0):

Using **Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild 2.3.3** instead. (have the issue with 2.2.2).

This is my csproj (do not need to add Microsoft.TypeScript.Compiler package)

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81;</PackageTargetFallback>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild" Version="2.3.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Note: Based on my test, Typescript 2.1 is available for Hosted VS2017 agent.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Updating Microsoft.Typescript.MSBuild to 2.3.3 resulted in different build errors in VSTS such as "Cannot find module '@angular/core'" and all other angular modules. However I can still build and run fine in my machine after the upgrade to 2.3.3. Thoughts?

Comment: Can you share a simple application on the onedrive?

Comment: What's the result if you use typescript 2.1 directly? (Remove Microsoft.Typescript.MSBuild and Microsoft.TypeScript.Compiler packages)