# VSTS Specified TypeScript compiler not found

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, compiler-errors, azure-pipelines

I am using VSTS for a project that is using TypeScript. We have a CI Build configured and suddenly that one stopped working today. Yesterday all was fine, today they are all failing.

Looking into the build logs I discovered that it's not finding the TypeScript compiler that we specified:

> Warning : Your project specifies TypeScriptToolsVersion 2.1, but a matching compiler was not found. The latest available TypeScript compiler will be used (2.4). To remove this warning, install the TypeScript 2.1 SDK or update the value of TypeScriptToolsVersion.

So all of a sudden it starts compiling with TypeScript 2.4 and we have some code that's not compatible with that version (Promises).

I have defined the TypeScript Tools Version in our .csproj as

```
<TypeScriptToolsVersion>2.1</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
```

and that seems to be working as I read in the build logs that it tried using that one first.

Any idea what caused VSTS suddenly to "forget" about TypeScript 2.1 and how I can fix this? I could not find any update notification or anything.

Comment: What's the result after trying my solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That means the TypeScript SDK has been updated on build server. If you are using private build agent, you can check it on your build server. If you are using Hosted agent, it will be updated irregularly (official article isn’t updated)

Regarding this issue, you can refer to these threads:

For VS 2015 project (Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild package): [Visual Studio Team Services build Typescript error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40441320/visual-studio-team-services-build-typescript-error)

For VS 2017 project (Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild package): [Angular4.1 with .NET Core1.1 build fails in VSTS Hosted VS2017 agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44221270/angular4-1-with-net-core1-1-build-fails-in-vsts-hosted-vs2017-agent)

Comment: I find it still very strange that the TypeScript version seems to have been updated without any notice on VSTS. I solved it by downloading a Nuget of the Typescript Compiler and I am using the version of this Nuget in the build (configured through the .csproj). Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 48):

Right click on Project and click properties
Click on TypeScriptBuild and Select Use Latest Available

[image: See Image Below]

Comment: this is what helped me.

Comment: 100% thanks - this error had been bugging me forever!